# jQuery - remove select option :selected attribute on click

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a multiselect that pops up in a modal dialog.  When the dialog closes, I'm populating a `<ul>` with `<li>`'s that contain text from the `:selected` options.  When each individual `<li>` is clicked, I want the `<li>` to fade away and the corresponding `:selected` `<option>` to become unselected.  I have everything working except unselecting the `<option>`.

Here's my code:

```
$('.control-finished').click(function(){
            $('ul.multiselect-dropdown-options-'+name+'').empty();
            $('option:selected', select).each(function(index, value) {
                var livalue = $(this).attr('value');
                $('ul.multiselect-dropdown-options-'+name+'').append('<li class="dropdown-option '+livalue+'">'+$(value).text()+'<!-- <a class="remove-option '+livalue+'"> -->x</li>');
                $('li.dropdown-option').click(function(){
                    $(this).fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).remove(); });
                    $('option:selected', this).removeAttr('selected');
                });
            });         

        });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think that you cannot remove :selected state.. Or you can, but the item will still be visually selected in the selectbox. Maybe you could just select different option (i.e. first one)?

Comment: wow, there are a lot of weirdness dealing with list boxes.  In summary, look at my post below.  Using .prop('selected','') turns out to be the best option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe your problem is on this line:

```
$('option:selected', this).removeAttr('selected');
```

This is saying, find all option:selected that is a descendent of li.dropdown-option.  But you're deleting these after the fadeout, so of course it's not going to find it.

So you need to change the 2nd parameter in the jQuery function above.  (this), to the actual parent dom element you wish to search under.

I don't know what your HTML looks like, so I can't provide you with a more detailed solution.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem
I tried

```
removeAttr('selected');

removeProp('selected');

prop('selected',false);
```

changing the select box value by

```
$('#selectboxID').val(newVal);
```

...

but still the selected attributes was there even with an empty value.

I finally did the following to get rid of it:

```
$('#selectboxID').html($('#selectboxID').html().replace('selected',''));
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me and worked while in cases wherein we need to manipulate Ajax data,

```
$('#id option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    $('option:selected').attr('selected', '');
```

or for single select box

```
    $('#selectboxID').attr('selected', '-1');
```

But then again, your actually binding a click function inside your each function, and trying to remove a selected value on select boxes inside a 'this' scope after you've already used remove() on the same 'this' scope?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this option selector.

```
$('#selectselector > option[selected="selected"]').removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/mmBKf/3/

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('ul').empty();

    $('option:selected').each(function() {
        $('<li></li>').text($(this).val()).appendTo($('ul'));
    });
});

$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('option[value="' + $(this).text() + '"]').prop('selected','');
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this. hope this helps you.

```
  var $element = $("#DropDownList1");
    $element.change(function () {
       $element.find('option').removeAttr('selected')
       .filter("[value=" + this.value + "]")
       .attr("selected", "selected");
       console.log(this.value);
    });
```

cheers.